# Can google vision API detect specific faces?

Tags: google-vision

Can I use google's vision API to not only detect faces on a specific picture but to detect which person is in the picture ?
Can this be done for celebrities (or ppl which can be easily find via a google search) automatically ? For unfamiliar ppl via some learning/look-alike mechanism ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  From the Google Vision API description:

> Face Detection
>   Detect multiple faces within an image, along with the associated key facial attributes like emotional state or wearing headwear. **Facial Recognition is not supported**.

But, you can implement facial recognition yourself using OpenCV.  I don't know your preferred language, but [here is a tutorial](http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html) on how to implement facial recognition in Python.  OpenCV also has interfaces for C++ and Java.